# Extracting accounts from sqlite3 database with python

Tags: python, sql, authentication, sqlite, account

I am making an approval system to my account management system. Upon registering the user has an entry in the database as Approved which is set to false, but when an admin logs in, I want him to be returned a list of accounts with the approved row as False. I have tried with this SQL statement but am only getting the first not all of them.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE approved=?", (False,))
ifapproved=c.fetchone()
print (ifapproved)
```

I have tried using a for loop but it just repeats the first account which is unapproved. How can I fix this?

Comment: i suppose remove , after false and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong syntx in your `execute` method.

For example:

> cur.execute("SELECT Name, Price FROM Cars WHERE Id=:Id", {"Id": uId})

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE approved=:approved", {"approved":'false'}) 
//with or without the single quite to false.
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print (row)  //check all list of returned results
```

or

> c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE approved = 'False'")
>
> c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE approved = 'false'")
>
> c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE approved = '0'")

Comment: wt is difference between ur answer and Below one

Comment: Does not work, still getting the first account only.

Comment: syntax it is? have u tried without the quetos on False

Comment: I removed the quotes and kept it as False, because approved is equal to the boolean False or True, not the string 'False' or 'True'

Comment: try now , you have used fetchOne ...with a select * query so fetch all as above and play with the row in the for loop ..cheers!

Comment: Thank you that worked! Do you what the SQL query is to updated the account to turn Approved into True?

Comment: your last question i didnt understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51258/discussion-between-coder77-and-danielad)

Comment: I've moved it into a chat, to avoid discussion in comments!

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
stmt="""SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE approved=:APPROVAL"""
d["APPROVAL"]=False

 c.execute(unicode(stmt), d)
ifapproved=c.fetchone()
print (ifapproved)
```

Comment: I get an error, d is not globally defined. I am using Python3 btw.